# ListView onItemClick event return wrong position with error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView which displays certain titles(Strings)

```
String[] navTitles = new String[] {Home, HR, company, joiner, next};
```

These titles are shown in the ListView. When the first item is clicked, I have to display a certain list, else if any other title is clicked I have to show a different list. The first (default) list should be the one which appears on clicking the first item. The issue is,if I click on a title, the list related to the next title is displayed. When I click the last title i get an error:-

```
    05-02 04:47:38.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1490): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
05-02 04:47:38.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.abc.attini.Home.displayView(Home.java:600)
```

When I click the second title, the `position` return as 2 instead of 1.

Here is my code:--

```
for(int j =0 ;j <navMenuTitles.length && j<iconColors.length;j++)
            {

                    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[j], iconColors[j])); 


            }
  adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
  private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener 
            {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) 
        {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item


            displayView(position);
        }
    }



    private void displayView(int position) 
    {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if(position==0)
        {
            fragment = new HomeFragment(SPHostUrl,encodedAccountName,deviceAuthKey,usersname,avatarUrl, fullName,getApplicationContext(),myFinalNewsList);
        }
        else
        {
            String myPosition = null;

            myPosition =  navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle(); //Line 600


            companyNewsList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(myFinalNewsList, new ArticleFilter(myPosition)));
             fragment = new HomeFragment(SPHostUrl,encodedAccountName,deviceAuthKey,usersname,avatarUrl, fullName,getApplicationContext(),companyNewsList);

        }
```

Comment: @Hemant it is the same question. But I tried making it more clear here

Comment: have you add header in "ListView" ?

Comment: Then you should do it in previous question.

Comment: @user3534519 u have to clear in old one not create another one

Comment: @Hemant ill keep that in mind and delete the old one

Comment: @Haresh with your hint, I removed the Header, now it works fine. But I need to have the header. Any help on that

Comment: @user3534519,Hi look at my ans

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
  {
       if(position>0){
         displayView(position-1);
       }
  }
```